# aws - easiest config for web app

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

I am new to AWS and the variety of options is overwhelming.

I run my app localy in docker. Now I want to move it to AWS so I can access it in browser remotely. What is the easiest configuration for my case?

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to AWS, I suggest it would be better to take a minute to understand what and how AWS works.

However, for your scenario, assuming you are good with docker, you can follow the [this tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-basics.html). AWS has a container service called ECS and I suggest you stick to it.